# How to make JTextArea scrollable to user input?

Tags: java, jtextarea, scrollable

I have been working on a java application since a few days (I am a novice). I have to make use of `JTextArea` for user input(250 characters). I have used `setPreferredSize()` method to resize my `JTextArea`. However, as the user types, when the inserted words exceed the `JTextArea` height, I cannot see the rest of the input though the user types.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: 1. Don’t use setPreferredSize, use the `setRows` and `setColumns` methods.  2. Make sure you place the JTextArea in a JScrollPane, and add the JScrollPane, not the JTextArea, to your panel or window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please post some code so we can see what you did already.
What you can try is add a `JScrollPane`:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Frame");
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea ("Textarea");

JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane (textArea, 
   JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

frame.add(scroll);//add Scrollbar to frame
```

Answer (score -2):

Please follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052473/scrollbars-in-jtextarea/36988270#36988270)

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class ScrollingTextArea 
{
  JFrame f;
  JTextArea ta;
  JScrollPane scrolltxt;
  public ScrollingTextArea() 
    {
         // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

          f=new JFrame();
          f.setLayout(null);
          f.setVisible(true);
          f.setSize(500,500);
          ta=new JTextArea();
          ta.setBounds(5,5,100,200);

          scrolltxt=new JScrollPane(ta);
          scrolltxt.setBounds(3,3,400,400);

          f.add(scrolltxt);

    }

     public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        new ScrollingTextArea();
    }
```

}

Comment: (1-) Don't use a null layout. Swing is designed to work with layout managers. The scrollbars will appear automatically when the preferred size of the text area is greater than the size of the scrollpane. The `ta.setBounds(...)` does nothing. The layout manager of the scrollpane will determine the size of the text area.