# Make JTextArea scrollable in Swing

Tags: java, swing

How can I make it so my `JTextArea` is scrollable. I want to make it so that `keysDisplay` has a scrollbar which can be used to scroll through the text area. I have skipped some unrealated code in `jFramePrint()`.

```
public class ApplicationViewer extends JFrame {

    private JTabbedPane tabs = new JTabbedPane();
    private JTextArea keyGenDisplay = new JTextArea();
    private JTextArea keysDisplay = new JTextArea();

    private JPanel controlPanel = new JPanel();
    private JButton addNumber = new JButton("Add Number");
    private JButton addLetter = new JButton("Add Letter");
    private JButton addHyphen = new JButton("Add Hyphen");
    private JButton calculateButton = new JButton("Calculate Key");

    private JTextField amountField = new JTextField("", 6);
    private JLabel amountLabel = new JLabel("  Amount of Keys :   ");
    private JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(keysDisplay);

    public void jFramePrint() {

        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.add(controlPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


        controlPanel.add(addNumber);
        controlPanel.add(addLetter);
        controlPanel.add(addHyphen);
        controlPanel.add(amountLabel);
        controlPanel.add(amountField);
        controlPanel.add(calculateButton);

        this.add(scroll);

        this.setSize(1400, 900);
        this.setTitle("Key Generator");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        keyGenDisplay.append("Key Format: ");
        keysDisplay.append("Keys Here: ");

        tabs.add("Key Generator", keyGenDisplay);
        tabs.add("Keys", keysDisplay);

        this.add(tabs);
        this.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052473/scrollbars-in-jtextarea

Comment: Use proper formatting when you post code. You have 1, 2, 3 spaces used for indentation on each line. This makes the code hard to read. If you want us to spend the time helping, then the least you can do is post readable code!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
private JTextArea keysDisplay = new JTextArea();
```

First of all you should use something like:

```
private JTextArea keysDisplay = new JTextArea(5, 20);
```

This will allow the text area to calculate its own preferred size. Scrollbars will then work properly when added to a scrollpane and more than 5 rows of text are added to the text area.

```
this.add(scroll);

...

this.add(tabs);
```

Your frame is using a `BorderLayout`. When you don't use a constraint then "CENTER is used by default.

You can't add multile components to the same area of the `BorderLayout`. So only the last component added is displayed.

Specify a different constraint for the tabs component.