# Can't add scroll bar to JTextarea

Tags: java

Hello Everyone I am new to Java so I am sure I am doing something obviously wrong here but I just keep going in circles.

I am trying to add a scroll to a JTextarea. Here is what I have tried but it doesn't show up.

```
    textarea1 = new JTextArea();
    textarea1.setBounds(251,26,795,345);
    textarea1.setBackground(new Color(255,255,255));
    textarea1.setForeground(new Color(0,0,0));
    textarea1.setEnabled(true);
    textarea1.setFont(new Font("sansserif",0,12));
    textarea1.setText("");
    textarea1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(1));
    textarea1.setVisible(true);
    JScrollPane ScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(textarea1);
    ScrollPane1.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);





    //adding components to contentPane panel
    contentPane.add(browseFileOne);
    contentPane.add(browseOutput);
    contentPane.add(button1);
    contentPane.add(button2);
    contentPane.add(button4);
    contentPane.add(fileOneText);
    contentPane.add(fileTwoText);
    contentPane.add(label1);
    contentPane.add(label2);
    contentPane.add(label3);
    contentPane.add(outputTextFile);
    contentPane.add(textarea1);
```

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052473/scrollbars-in-jtextarea

Comment: Use the `JTextArea` [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#JTextArea-int-int-) that takes the number of rows and columns.

Comment: _Here is what I have tried but it doesn't show up_ You should try to post a [mcve], then I can try what you have tried so that I can see what you mean by _it doesn't show up_

Comment: Thank you for the feedback!!! I got it working I didn't realize that the ScrollPane basically takes over for the textarea and all I really needed to do was only add the scroll pane to the content pane not the texture as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see working example:

https://repl.it/repls/DimpledDefensiveSourcecode

Code:

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        this.setSize(400, 400);
        this.setLocation(0, 0);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setTitle("Application");
        JPanel painel = new JPanel(null);
        // Creating the Input
        JTextField tf1 = new JTextField("Some random text", 15);
        tf1.setBounds(5, 5, this.getWidth() - 120, 20);
        tf1.setColumns(10);
        tf1.setText("Omg");

        // resultsTA,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        painel.add(tf1);
        // Creating the button
        JButton button1 = new JButton("Send");
        button1.setBounds(290, 5, 100, 19);
        painel.add(button1);
        // Creating the TextArea
        JTextArea ta1 = new JTextArea(15, 20);
        JScrollPane scr = new JScrollPane(ta1,
                JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);// Add your text area to scroll pane 
        ta1.setBounds(5, 35, 385, 330);
        ta1.setLineWrap(true);
        ta1.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        scr.setBounds(20, 30, 100, 40);// You have to set bounds for all the controls and containers incas eof null layout
        painel.add(scr);// Add you scroll pane to container
        this.add(painel);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: `JPanel painel = new JPanel(null);` I think it is preferrable to use a [layout manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)